# Why QPushButton.resize() don't work in QVBoxLayout?

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm making a UI, as shown in the figure.

For the four buttons in the middle (ops_area), I used QVBoxLayout to manage them. I used resize() to set the size of the buttons, but the size of the buttons did not change.
[image]

```
...

    btn_add_model_to_selectedModels_area_ = new QPushButton(">", this);
    btn_add_model_to_selectedModels_area_->resize(40, 30);

    btn_add_model_to_selectedModels_area_->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

    btn_add_all_models_to_selectedModels_area_ = new QPushButton(">>", this);
    btn_add_all_models_to_selectedModels_area_->resize(40, 30);

    btn_delete_model_from_selectedModels_area_ = new QPushButton("<", this);
    btn_delete_model_from_selectedModels_area_->resize(40, 30);

    btn_delete_all_models_from_selectedModels_area_ = new QPushButton("<<", this);
    btn_delete_all_models_from_selectedModels_area_->resize(40, 30);


...

    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QHBoxLayout *modelLibrary_load_delete_btn_area_ = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QHBoxLayout *selectedModels_confirm_cancel_btn_area_ = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    QVBoxLayout *modelLibrary_area = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QVBoxLayout *ops_area = new QVBoxLayout(this);

...

    ops_area->addStretch(0);
    ops_area->addWidget(btn_add_model_to_selectedModels_area_);
    ops_area->addWidget(btn_add_all_models_to_selectedModels_area_);
    ops_area->addWidget(btn_delete_model_from_selectedModels_area_);
    ops_area->addWidget(btn_delete_all_models_from_selectedModels_area_);
    ops_area->addStretch(0);
```

What is the correct way to make a fixed size button? How can I fixed it?

Comment: use `->setFixedSize(40, 30)`

Comment: yeah, that is the right answer!@eyllanesc

Comment: You can also set a fixed size in QtDesigner directly, or set a minimum size, depending on your needs.